# How to add elastic bounce effect to JQuery Mobile Page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, easing

What's the best method to implement an **elastic bounce effect** when vertically scrolling to the end or top of a page?

I have tried [iScroll](http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll5/demos/simple/) but its seems a little heavy for such a basic and commonplace effect. Perhaps it can be achieved through a native jQuery mobile interface call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FancyScroll.js](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/09/24/fancyscroll-js-add-an-iosandroid-overflow-scroll-effect/) will give an effect like this. But for me [iScroll 5](http://iscrolljs.com) is the best solution at the moment.